# Node.js Selenium driver.quit(); not running

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

The Function is supposed to open the link (it's an adfly link), wait til the timer is done and click skip ad, wait til the youtube page loods, and then load `exit(start);` and close the browser. However, the `browser.quit();` does not run.

Here is the function I am Working with. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function test(start){
  (async function init() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
    try{
        // Navigate to Url
        await driver.get('http://raboninco.com/KY6z');
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 8000));
        var click_skip = driver.findElement(By.id('skip_bu2tton')).click();
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 19000));
    }
    finally{
        driver.quit();
        exit(start);
    }
  })();
}
```

And here is the exit function:

```
function exit(start){
  var time = Date.now() - start;
  console.log(`\n\x1b[1m\x1b[37mFinished in ${time}ms. \x1b[32mSuccess: ${successes} \x1b[37m- \x1b[31mErrors: ${errors} \x1b[37m`);
  process.exit();
}
```

Any help I can get would be lovely! Thanks.